# Having multiple page_url in one class using page-object gem + ruby

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

I have 6 product pages that are all pretty much the same for the purpose of functional testing. Their differences are only in the description and images which I don't do anything with at this time. This is my current_setup:
base page: product_page.rb

```
class ProductPage
  button(:add_fruit_proceed, :id => add_fruit)
  text_field(:fruit_quantity, :id => fruit_quantity)
end
```

The product pages all look similar to this: apple_page.rb

```
class ApplePage < ProductPage
  page_url "#{domain}/fruit/apple"
end
```

Is there a way to consolidate all these so that I only have product_page.rb? I need the page_url as I do use visit(ApplePage) in my tests.

Comment: How does the page_url differ between the multiple pages? Is it just the fruit name that changes (ex another url would be "#{domain}/fruit/banana") or is it something more complex?

Comment: Yes most of the urls are similar "#{domain}/fruit/banana" or "#{domain}/veg/squash"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `page_url` could be changed to:

```
page_url "#{domain}/<%=params[:category]%>/<%=params[:type]%>"
```

The page object gem uses ERB to allow you to create a page url template, which allows substitution of the params later - ie when calling visit.

To visit the page, you would have to specify the category and type in the `using params`:

```
visit ProductPage, using_params: {category: 'fruit', type: 'apple'} do |page|
  # Do stuff with the domain/fruit/apple page
end
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. I didn't think of this. Just remembered a previous example you gave similar to that.